# How can I get scponly working again?

Tags: 10.04, upgrade

I had a working installation of scponly when I had Ubuntu 9.10, and then I upgraded to 10.04, as per the advice here:

https://askubuntu.com/questions/50247/moving-information-from-ubuntu-9-10-server-to-ubuntu-11-04

However, it appears that scponly is broken in Ubuntu 10.04:

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/scponly/+bug/668366

This functionality is absolutely mission critical, and its lack is causing us serious problems.  How can I get this functionality back?

**EDIT**: I tried the suggestions here:

https://help.ubuntu.com/10.04/serverguide/C/ftp-server.html

But all my previous users don't work anymore either.  I really need this to work...

Answer (score 1):

At hcc hobbynet we use [mysecureshell](http://mysecureshell.sourceforge.net/)

works great for that purpsus no shell access but the ability access  files on the server.

Ans also nice feuter is locking them in there home dir